# Python's request.get only show 200 status

Tags: python, api, python-requests, cisco

I'm trying to workd with the Cisco Prime API, and it seems to work when using Postman (the output is an xml file). However, when I try to reproduce the same with Python:

```
request.get(url, verify=False, auth=credentials)
print(response)
```

the only response I get is `<Response [200]>` (and a warning for disabling SSL, but that's not relevant)... I use requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth to generate the "crdentials" variable

Comment: What response are you expecting?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for python requests? What you probably want is `r = requests.get(...)` and `print(r.text)|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, of course, it's just after posting this that I found the answer: first, you need to search for the json, not the xml and second, when you want to cast the json, you need do
    response.json()

Answer (score 3):

You need to get with

```
print(response.json())
```

Or

```
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this to get a response as text

```
 response = request.get(url, verify=False, auth=credentials)
   print response.text
```

that's it best luck